# How can I change $ to > in terminal?

Tags: command-line, .profile

In any terminal there is specific meaning of `puneet@Puneet-Ubuntu-PC:~$`I want to replace '$' symbol with '>'.

Please guide me How can I make this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `.bashrc` file with your favorite text editor. In my case I used nano. Find the line that looks like

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

In my case it was at line 53. Replace it with:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]> '
```

And you are done. Open a new terminal to see changes.

Comment: I believe there's an error at the very end of your replacement line. Shouldn't it end in `\> '`?

Comment: @heynnema Nopes. Actually \ is used to print special characters which has other meanings. And as far as I know \ was used before `$` so that `$` isn't mistaken as staring of new command. **PS**: I tested both the situations before writing the answer. If I consider \ prompt is like `\>`. And Formatting comment with \ is giving me a headache

Comment: Fair enough! Good job.